# Have background change color on refresh in sequence?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having a bit of trouble stringing together something that would change the color of the background every time you refresh the page, but in a sequence. I'm savvy with a lot of basic HTML, but not too much with java/css. I'm trying to have my background change along with some pictures for a page I'm working on, and I've figured out a code for the pictures to change on refresh, but I'm extremely confused on getting similar results with the background. Here's the code I have for the pictures:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

            function loadNextImage1() {
                //get image object
                var myImg = document.getElementById('ImageRefresh');

                //declare image directory path and image array
                var thePath = "http://";
                var theImages = new Array();
                theImages[0] = "url";
                theImages[1] = "url";
                theImages[2] = "url";

                //get current cookie value
                var currentIndex = parseInt(getCookie());
                var imgPath = thePath + theImages[currentIndex];
                myImg.src = imgPath;

                //set next cookie index
                currentIndex += 1;
                if(currentIndex > (theImages.length - 1)) {
                    currentIndex = 0;
                }
                setCookie(currentIndex);
            }

            function setCookie(someint) {
                var now = new Date();
                var addDays = now.getDate() + 7
                now.setDate(addDays); // cookie expires in 7 days
                var theString = 'imgID=' + escape(someint) + ';expires=' + now.toUTCString();
                document.cookie = theString;
            }

            function getCookie() {
                var output = "0";
                if(document.cookie.length > 0) {
                    var temp = unescape(document.cookie);
                    temp = temp.split(';');
                    for(var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                        if(temp[i].indexOf('imgID') != -1) {
                            temp = temp[i].split('=');
                            output = temp.pop();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return output;
            }
</script>

<body onload="loadNextImage1();">

<img id="ImageRefresh">
```

Is there something similar I can do to make the background change on refresh as well? I figured I could make the background just a picture of the color I want, but I can't apply the img id to the head. If this is something like super simple please forgive me, a lot of this stuff is like a foreign language to me.

**EDIT:** Here's my current coding with a background color changer that halts the sequence entirely.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            function loadNextImage1() {
                //get image object
                var myImg = document.getElementById('Sidebar1');

                //declare image directory path and image array
                var thePath = "http://";
                var theImages = new Array();
                theImages[0] = "URL";
                theImages[1] = "URL";
                theImages[2] = "URL";

                //get current cookie value
                var currentIndex = parseInt(getCookie());
                var imgPath = thePath + theImages[currentIndex];
                myImg.src = imgPath;

                //set next cookie index
                currentIndex += 1;
                if(currentIndex > (theImages.length - 1)) {
                    currentIndex = 0;
                }
                setCookie(currentIndex);
            }

            function setCookie(someint) {
                var now = new Date();
                var addDays = now.getDate() + 7
                now.setDate(addDays); // cookie expires in 7 days
                var theString = 'imgID=' + escape(someint) + ';expires=' + now.toUTCString();
                document.cookie = theString;
            }

            function getCookie() {
                var output = "0";
                if(document.cookie.length > 0) {
                    var temp = unescape(document.cookie);
                    temp = temp.split(';');
                    for(var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                        if(temp[i].indexOf('imgID') != -1) {
                            temp = temp[i].split('=');
                            output = temp.pop();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return output;
            }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

            function loadNextImage2() {
                //get image object
                var myImg = document.getElementById('Sidebar2');

                //declare image directory path and image array
                var thePath = "https://";
                var theImages = new Array();
                theImages[0] = "URL";
                theImages[1] = "URL";
                theImages[2] = "URL";

                //get current cookie value
                var currentIndex = parseInt(getCookie());
                var imgPath = thePath + theImages[currentIndex];
                myImg.src = imgPath;

                //set next cookie index
                currentIndex += 1;
                if(currentIndex > (theImages.length - 1)) {
                    currentIndex = 0;
                }
                setCookie(currentIndex);
            }

            function setCookie(someint) {
                var now = new Date();
                var addDays = now.getDate() + 7
                now.setDate(addDays); // cookie expires in 7 days
                var theString = 'imgID=' + escape(someint) + ';expires=' + now.toUTCString();
                document.cookie = theString;
            }

            function getCookie() {
                var output = "0";
                if(document.cookie.length > 0) {
                    var temp = unescape(document.cookie);
                    temp = temp.split(';');
                    for(var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                        if(temp[i].indexOf('imgID') != -1) {
                            temp = temp[i].split('=');
                            output = temp.pop();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return output;
            }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

            function changeColor() {

            //declare image directory path and image array
            var colors = ["#00ffff", "#ff00ff", "ffff00"];
            colors[0] = "#00ffff";
            colors[1] = "#ff00ff";
            colors[2] = "#ffff00";

            //get current cookie value
            var currentIndex = parseInt(getCookie());
            var background = colors[currentIndex];

            document.body.style.backgroundColor = background;

            //set next cookie index
            currentIndex += 1;
            currentIndex %= colors.length;
            setCookie(currentIndex);
        }

        function setCookie(someint) {
            var now = new Date();
            var addDays = now.getDate() + 7
            now.setDate(addDays); // cookie expires in 7 days
            var theString = 'imgID=' + escape(someint) + ';expires=' + now.toUTCString();
            document.cookie = theString;
        }

        function getCookie() {
            var output = "0";
            if(document.cookie.length > 0) {
                var temp = unescape(document.cookie);
                temp = temp.split(';');
                for(var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                    if(temp[i].indexOf('imgID') != -1) {
                        temp = temp[i].split('=');
                        output = temp.pop();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return output;
        }

</script>

<body onload="loadNextImage1(); loadNextImage2(); changeColor();">
```

Comment: firstly, typo: `<body onload="loadNextImage1();">` (missing "). secondly - with javascript you can set css styles on any element (eg the body element)... which includes the "background" property. I'd look into changing the colour of the background that way

Comment: Easiest way: `localStorage` for the refresh count, _class_ attribute on `<body>` for how it should be styled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same script working with backgroundColor now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            function loadNextImage1() {

            //declare image directory path and image array
            var colors = ["#eee", "#123123", "red"];
            colors[0] = "#eee";
            colors[1] = "#123";
            colors[2] = "red";

            //get current cookie value
            var currentIndex = parseInt(getCookie());
            var background = colors[currentIndex];

            document.body.style.backgroundColor = background;

            //set next cookie index
            currentIndex += 1;
            currentIndex %= colors.length;
            setCookie(currentIndex);
        }

        function setCookie(someint) {
            var now = new Date();
            var addDays = now.getDate() + 7
            now.setDate(addDays); // cookie expires in 7 days
            var theString = 'imgID=' + escape(someint) + ';expires=' + now.toUTCString();
            document.cookie = theString;
        }

        function getCookie() {
            var output = "0";
            if(document.cookie.length > 0) {
                var temp = unescape(document.cookie);
                temp = temp.split(';');
                for(var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                    if(temp[i].indexOf('imgID') != -1) {
                        temp = temp[i].split('=');
                        output = temp.pop();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return output;
        }

</script>

<body onload="loadNextImage1();">

<img id="ImageRefresh">
```

Comment: I'm making progress with that code, as the background's color changed when I put it in, however the sequence stopped to a halt and the page is the same every time I rotate it (images and all), any idea on what the problem may be?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML5 `localStorage` (or use `sessionStorage` if you want to keep the session) to save the index:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function loadNextImage1() 
    {
        //get image object
        var myImg = document.getElementById('ImageRefresh');

        //declare image directory path and image array
        var thePath = "http://";
        var theImages = new Array();
        theImages[0] = "url";
        theImages[1] = "url";
        theImages[2] = "url";

        // Remember to JSON parse it later
        var local = localStorage.getItem('backgroundImageIndex');

        // If local is null, then no localStorage (i.e. first load)
        var currentIndex = (local === null) ? 0 : JSON.parse(local);

        // Reset to 0 if bigger than 2
        currentIndex = (currentIndex > 2) ? 0 : currentIndex;

        // Set src
        myImg.src = thePath + theImages[currentIndex];

        // Write to localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('backgroundImageIndex', JSON.stringify(currentIndex));
    }
</script>

<body onload="loadNextImage1();>

<img id="ImageRefresh">
```